# Unable to install matplotlib on Mac Mountain Lion - "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: python, matplotlib, osx-mountain-lion

I have been trying to install matplotlib through easy_install(easy_install-2.7 for python2.7) and by building from source(https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib).

But both fail with the error - "error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Not sure if it helps, but more of the error messaging here: http://pastebin.com/FiTth4kG

Prior to this i had successfully managed to install all other scientific libraries that i needed - numpy, scipy, pandas, sklearn. But am getting stuck with matplotlib.

To facilitate installations of numpy et al, i had installed quite a few other packages. (I 
dont't even remember which all)

I fear the worst and assume that some of these related package installations might have impacted some default setting on my Terminal.

All other solutions on SE point to having XCode and XCode command tools installed. 
But i have the latest version of both.

I see that my usr/bin/ has both gcc & gcc-4.2

Python verion being used - Python2.7
OS - Mac Mountain Lion

I have torn off half of my hair trying to get this installed. 
Please please heeeelp... before i go completely bald.

*UPDATE: i have got it working by installing the .dmg (don't ask why i did not try that before - the easiest solution is at times the best solution)*

But still want to know the reason for the above errors.
I suspect i might encounter this menace on future installations.

Comment: It looks like a missing header file. But it also looks like you haven't included all of your error message in the paste bin. I would've thought there's more at the top, which may indicate which header file it is having problems finding (I suspect the Python.h one; which requires setting an include path correctly).

Comment: @Evert...Sorry about that. Didn't paste the whole messaging. I retried installing using a virtualenv. The error persists. The whole messaging can be found here: http://pastebin.com/FiTth4kG .Edited the question too.

Comment: How did you install `numpy`? Looks like a diy install, and the best I can see are incompatibilities with the `numpy` installation. `numpy` is already installed on OSX, so if it all possible, use that one. In fact, your current `numpy` says "...py2.7-macosx-10.5-intel.egg/..."; that's not Mountain Lion.

Comment: Thanks @Evert . I didn't even know that OSX shipped with it's own version of numpy. I installed numpy myself. (easy_install if memory serves me right). On my Python 'numpy.__version__' throws up '1.8.0.dev-Unknown'. How do i revert to the OSX version?

Comment: If it's still relevant: find out where that numpy is installed, then just remove or rename out. Find out from the Python prompt with `numpy.__file__`, then rename or remove that directory. Then try again importing `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Your errors seem related to treetype and/or numpy from OS X. If you have trouble with the (older) numpy shipped by OS X, you may want to give my homebrew-python tap a try. Then, install matplotlib with `pip` like so (you need [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install python         # avoid the need for sudo pip
brew install freetype
brew install libpng
brew tap samueljohn/python  # adding numpy, scipy and pillow (PIL) formulae
brew install numpy
pip install matplotlib
```

If you use the brewed python like shown here, it will be built with clang (yay!) and distutils will also make use of clang if you later build things with `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) then try:

```
brew install freetype
brew link freetype
brew install libpng
brew link libpng
pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: No luck with that either :( Already had freetype & libpng installed and linked. On doing "brew install matplotlib" within my virtualenv it throws: _Error: No available formula for matplotlib_

Comment: Which is why it says `pip install matplotlib` and not `brew install matplotlib` :)